# Does using calculated fields in Access increase efficiency

Tags: sql, ms-access, database-design, calculated-field

I have a database that keeps track of attendance for students in a school. There's one table (`SpecificClasses`) with dates of all of the classes, and another table (`Attendance`) with a list of all the students in each class and their attendance on that day.

The school wants to be able to view that data in many different ways and to filter it according to many different parameters. (I won't paste the entire query here because it is quite complicated and the details are not important for my question.) One of their options they want is to view the attendance of a specific student on a certain day of the week. Meaning, they want to be able to notice if a student is missing every Tuesday or something like that.

To make the query be able to do that, I have used `DatePart("w",[SpecificClasses]![Day])`. However, running this on every class (when we may be talking about hundreds of classes taken by one student in one semester) is quite time-consuming. So I was thinking of storing the day of the week manually in the `SpecificClasses` table, or perhaps even in the `Attendance` table to be able to avoid making a join, and just being very careful in my events to keep this data up-to-date (meaning to fill in the info when the secretaries insert a new SpecificClass or fix the `Day` field).

Then I was wondering whether I could just make a calculated field that would store this value. (The school has Access 2010 so I don't have to worry about compatibility). If I create a calculated field, does Access actually store that field and remember it for the future and not have to recalculate it each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As HansUp mentions in his answer, a Calculated field cannot be indexed so it might not give you much of a performance boost. However, since you are using Access 2010 you could create a "real" Integer field named [WeekdayNumber] and put an index on it,

[image: TableDesign.png]

and then use a Before Change [data macro](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/create-a-data-macro-HA010378170.aspx) to insert the `Weekday()` value for you:

[image: BeforeChange.png]

(The `Weekday()` function gives the same result as `DatePart("w", ...)`.)

Comment: Cool. I see that Access 2010 has quite a few advantages over 2007 (which I originally used to write the database).

Answer (score 2):

> I was wondering whether I could just make a calculated field that
>   would store this value.

No, not for a calculated field expression which uses `DatePart()`.  Access supports a limited set of functions for calculated fields, and `DatePart()` is not one of those.

> If I create a calculated field, does Access actually store that field
>   and remember it for the future and not have to recalculate it each
>   time?

Doesn't apply to your current case.  But for a calculated field which Access would accept, yes, that is the way it works.

However a calculated field can not be indexed so that limits how much improvement it can offer in terms of data retrieval speed.  If you encounter another situation where you can create a valid calculated field, test the performance to see whether you notice any improvement (vs. calculating the value in a query).

For your `DatePart()` query problem, consider creating a calendar table with a row for each date and include the weekday number as a separate indexed field.  Then you could join the calendar table into your query, avoid the need to compute `DatePart()` again, and allow Access to use the indexed weekday number to quickly identify which rows match the weekday of interest.

Comment: A calculated field can use `Weekday()`, but your point about not being able to index calculated fields is a good one.

Comment: So if I would use `Weekday()`, it would give the advantage that it wouldn't have to be calculated every time, which is better than what I have now, but I wouldn't get the advantage of an index, so it is better to go with my own regularly updated field (like I basically suggested in the question and Gord Thompson suggested a way of implementing it)?

Comment: I think an indexed field maintained by a data macro should be a better (probably much better) option than a calculated field. The key factor is you want Access to use an index to identify which rows satisfy your `WHERE` condition.  Without an index, Access would need to examine *every* row from the source table in order to determine which of them satisfy the `WHERE`.  That means a full table scan --- which can be a real performance killer.  Avoid it if possible!

Comment: So my other use of calculated fields, `Student.LastnameFirstname` (defined as `Lastname & ", " & Firstname`) is a good use of calculated fields, because it's not used as a `WHERE` or `JOIN` in any queries and it comes up in dozens of reports and forms, so it would need to be recalculated all the time.

Comment: Maybe.  But if it's used for any `ORDER BY` or `GROUP BY`, an index would help performance.

Comment: I guess that's true. Maybe I should use `Lastname` and `Firstname` for ordering.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73611/discussion-between-hansup-and-clum).

Comment: The ACE data engine can likely pull 100,000 of these records in LESS then one second on a typical computer today. So looking to save 1/10,000th of a second with this process is likely a waste of time. If your query that pulls several 100 records is running slow then there is something VERY much wrong with the query. Attempting to save such super tiny amounts of processing with todays CPU’s that can do near a billion calculations in a second will not result in ANY KIND of noticeable increase in your application. Whatever approach reduces your human development cost is the likely the best choice